# Error while implementing Gaussian Regression. How to solve it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running a Gaussian regression in Python. My data set has the shape of (10000,5). But when I try to fit the model I get an error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'n_dims'`

How do I resolve this?

I initially thought this error is being caused as the dimension of my dependent variable might be different from the independent variable. But even after changing them to the same dimension, I am unable to find the problem with the code. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import (RBF, Matern, RationalQuadratic,
                                              ExpSineSquared, DotProduct,
                                              ConstantKernel)

data_set = pd.read_excel(r'XXXXX', sheet = 'Worksheet', header = 0)
data_set.head()
test_set = data_set

y = test_set.iloc[:,4]
test_set.drop(test_set.columns[4], axis = 1, inplace = True)    
X = test_set 
x=StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)   

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_test = np.array(y_test)
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (7000,1))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (3000,1))

kernels = [1.0 * RBF(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-1, 10.0))]

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernels)   
gp.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
File "<ipython-input-23-5a576449fdb6>", line 1, in <module>
    gp.fit(X_train, y_train)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\gpr.py", line 203, in fit
    if self.optimizer is not None and self.kernel_.n_dims > 0:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'n_dims'
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html) it seems that the kernel passed to the `GaussianProcessRegressor` should be a kernel object, but you seem to be passing a list.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Linda I kindly suggest you post this as an answer, so that OP can subsequently accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing the `GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernels)` the argument passed as `kernel` has to be a kernel object. You are passing a list.

More information in the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html).